# Multiple alignments textview android

Tags: android, alignment

What I want to do is have one word aligned on the far left side of a textview and one word aligned on the far right of the same textview. I have no idea how to do this. I'm using android studio. Whats the best, if not the only way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use RelativeLayout,

> RelativeLayout is a view group that displays child views in relative positions. The position of each view can be specified as relative to sibling elements (such as to the left-of or below another view) or in positions relative to the parent RelativeLayout area (such as aligned to the bottom, left or center).

Here you have two textview tv_1 at the most left and tv_2 at the most right (layout_alignParentRight="true"), and the tv_2 will follow tv_1 do to layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_1"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="left"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_1"/> </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be very hard to do that(Auto spacing between two words in a single `TextView`). Using 2 `TextView` is suggestive

Replace your `TextView` with this

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ?? I dont understand what you say.. Can you explain

Comment: If I move the first TextView to be in the center of the screen, the second TextView won't adjust itself to be to the right of the first textview

Comment: If you are talking about vertical middle. Check my answer once again. I asked him to "Replace your TextView with this". So where ever his current TextView is this will work well